# Display leaflet markers when moving on the map instead of after moving

Tags: leaflet

I'm using leaflet to show places on a map. When moving on the map leaflet waits the end of the move to display the new markers (the ones that were out of the map). I would like leaflet to display the new markers **while** moving, and not at the end.

Note that I'm using markers from leaflet-dvf which extends leaflet `L.Path`.

I looked at the [doc](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html) but found nothing (except from the `move` and `moveend` events but I didn't find how to force leaflet to display markers when `move` is triggered).

Is there any simple way (like a configuration thing) to do that ?

Comment: I guess you are using Circle Markers?

Comment: Actually I am using markers from leaflet-dvf (but I think leaflet handle them as classic circle markers). I will precise this in the post.